# Can i develop backend part of ios application on linux?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, linux

I have an ios application with backend in Ruby on Rails.
I have some issues with backend, So is it possible to work on backend on linux???

Answer (score 1):

You can develop the backend with any platform you like. Just make sure your iOS can communicate with it. I assume web services will be the best bet for that.

Comment: I am using AWS, So is it poosible?

Comment: Yes, like I say - your iOS app really should not care about the backend system and how it runs. All it needs to know are two things: How to connected to the backend (Web service calls) and how to read the data (XML, JAVA, JSOn) then parse the data it gets and stores it in NSObjects.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby on Rails runs on Apache2 and Linux is the best platform for running Apache2. On linux it is easiest to open port for web server and configure virtual host to run it locally. There are many tutorials how to do this on linux.